Win32 API makes only my last click-through label appears (overlay created in tkinter)
I am writing a tkinter overlay which is my main class. This class can display images at specific coordinate using tkinter label, however the images should be click-through. Therefore, I extended the label class to add a function that makes the label click-though using win32 api. And it work for 1 image.
The issue is that when I create a 2nd image the 1st one disappear and only the new images is visible and click through. I don't understand what's the issue.
Here my code:
import numpy as np
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import Label
import win32api
import win32con
import win32gui
import logging
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

class CustomLabel(tk.Label):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self._make_click_through()
        
    def _make_click_through(self):
        hwnd = self.winfo_id()
        wnd_exstyle = win32gui.GetWindowLong(hwnd, win32con.GWL_EXSTYLE)
        wnd_exstyle |= win32con.WS_EX_LAYERED | win32con.WS_EX_TRANSPARENT
        win32gui.SetWindowLong(hwnd, win32con.GWL_EXSTYLE, wnd_exstyle)
        win32gui.SetLayeredWindowAttributes(hwnd, win32api.RGB(0, 128, 0), 0, win32con.LWA_COLORKEY)


class Overlay(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        
        self._terminate = False
        self._visible = None
        self._x_offset = 0
        self._y_offset = 0
        self._width = 0
        self._height = 0
        self._transparent_color = '#008000'
        self._image_labels = []
        
        self.bind('<Escape>', self.stop)
        
    def terminate(self):
        self._terminate = True
    
    def _show(self, event):
        self.deiconify()
        
    def _hide(self, event):
        self.withdraw()
        
    def _close(self, event):
        self.quit()
    
    def _set_geometry(self, loc):
        self._x_offset = loc["x"]
        self._y_offset = loc["y"]
        self._width = loc["width"]
        self._height = loc["height"]
        self.geometry(f"{self._width}x{self._height}+{self._x_offset}+{self._y_offset}")
           
    def _init_ui(self):
        self.title("Map Overlay")
        self.overrideredirect(True)
        self.wm_attributes('-transparentcolor', self._transparent_color)
        self.wm_attributes("-topmost", True)
        self.configure(bg=self._transparent_color)

        
    def _toggle_visibility(self, event):
        if self._visible:
            self._hide(event)
        else:
            self._show(event) 
            logger.log("show")
        self._visible = not self._visible
    
    def start(self, map_config):
        self._set_geometry(map_config)
        self._init_ui()
        self._visible = True
        logger.info("Overlay Started.")
    
    def _display_image(self, np_image, x, y):
        try:
            pil_image = Image.fromarray(np_image)
            img_tk = ImageTk.PhotoImage(pil_image)
            label = CustomLabel(self, image=img_tk, bg=self._transparent_color, highlightthickness=0, bd = 0)
            label.image = img_tk
            label.configure(image=img_tk)
            label.place(x=x, y=y)
            self._image_labels.append(label)
            logger.info("Displayed NumPy image.")      
        except Exception as e:
            logger.error(f"Error displaying image: {e}")

    def _update_labels(self):
        return
        
    def run(self):
        self.after(1, self._update_labels)
        self.mainloop()

    def stop(self, event):
        self.destroy()
        logger.info("Overlay is closing...")
    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO,
                        format='%(asctime)s - %(threadName)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s',
                        handlers=[logging.StreamHandler()])
    map_config = {
        "x": 2130,
        "y": 1009,
        "width": 429,
        "height": 428
    }
    np_image1 = np.zeros((200, 200, 3), dtype=np.uint8)
    np_image2 = np.ones((100, 100, 3), dtype=np.uint8) * 255
    overlay = Overlay()
    overlay.start(map_config)
    overlay._display_image(np_image2, 100, 100)
    overlay._display_image(np_image1, 200, 200)
    overlay._display_image(np_image2, 300, 300)
    overlay.run()

Here the output without make_click_through:

Here the output with make_click-through:

I tried to set up the click through feature at multiple place of the code and also at different timings in case there are compatibility issues with tkinter processes. Nothing worked so far, I can only use click through feature on only one Image.

Where is pil_image defined? It looks like it might be some sort of global variable rather than a member of the class?

@JonathanPotter pil_image is defined at the begging of _display_image function its a PIL image and make the conversion between numpy and tkinter

I did not succeed using labels. However, I used canvas instead to support my images and it works perfectly well. Here the code I changed :
class CustomCanvas(tk.Canvas):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        #self._make_click_through()
        
    def _make_click_through(self):
        hwnd = self.winfo_id()
        wnd_exstyle = win32gui.GetWindowLong(hwnd, win32con.GWL_EXSTYLE)
        wnd_exstyle |= win32con.WS_EX_LAYERED | win32con.WS_EX_TRANSPARENT
        win32gui.SetWindowLong(hwnd, win32con.GWL_EXSTYLE, wnd_exstyle)
        win32gui.SetLayeredWindowAttributes(hwnd, win32api.RGB(0, 128, 0), 0, win32con.LWA_COLORKEY)

class Overlay:
    def _display_image(self, np_image, x, y):
            try:
                height, width, channels = np_image.shape
                pil_image = Image.fromarray(np_image)
                img_tk = ImageTk.PhotoImage(pil_image)
                canvas = CustomCanvas(self, width=width, height=height, bg=self._transparent_color, highlightthickness=0, bd = 0)
                canvas.create_image(width/2,height/2, image=img_tk)
                canvas.image = img_tk
                canvas.place(x=x, y=y)
                canvas._make_click_through()
                self._image_labels.append(canvas)
                logger.info("Displayed NumPy image.")      
            except Exception as e:
                logger.error(f"Error displaying image: {e}")

